# How to set Shadow for a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, shadow

I have this method `applyShadow` which applies the shadow , and this works fine for `UIViews` and for `UINavigationBar`,but When I try it to `UISegmentedControl`, it doesnt work.

```
     -(void) applyShadow
{
    [self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1.0)];
    [self.layer setShadowRadius:1.0];
    [self.layer setShadowOpacity:.15];
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    self.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
}
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
  [self.tabSegment applyShadow];
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not the best answer but try adding `UISegmentedControl` to a `UIView` as a subview. But be careful about setting the frames of each other the same.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a UIView behind the Segment bar didnt work out for me, so I did find a quick solution to it, I added a UIView below the segment bar and applies shadow to it.If anyone come up with a better solution,I always welcome them.

```
    self.shadowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 1)];
    self.shadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.shadowView applyShadow];
    [self.view addSubview:self.shadowView];
```

Comment: Isn't adding segment bar below the UIView adding segmented control as a  subview to UIView? @Mr.T